# XML Serialization format needs to be very specific, how do you serialize child classes that have the same name as their parent class?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm fairly new to programming and need to figure out how to serialize an object so that the XML file has the format shown below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OpenModelResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ResultOnMembers>
    <ResultOnMembers>
      <Members>
        <ResultOnMember>
          <Member>
            <MemberType>Member1D</MemberType>
            <Id>1</Id>
          </Member>
          <ResultType>InternalForces</ResultType>
          <Results>
            <ResultBase xsi:type="ResultOnSection">
              <AbsoluteRelative>Absolute</AbsoluteRelative>
              <Position>0</Position>
              <Results>
                <SectionResultBase xsi:type="ResultOfInternalForces">
                  <Loading>
                    <LoadingType>LoadCase</LoadingType>
                    <Id>1</Id>
                    <Items>
                      <ResultOfLoadingItem>
                        <Coefficient>1</Coefficient>
                      </ResultOfLoadingItem>
                    </Items>
                  </Loading>
                  <N>242.96484375</N>
                  <Qy>0</Qy>
                  <Qz>1176.9375</Qz>
                  <Mx>0</Mx>
                  <My>-727.5482177734375</My>
                  <Mz>0</Mz>
                </SectionResultBase>
                <SectionResultBase xsi:type="ResultOfInternalForces">
                  <Loading>
                    <LoadingType>LoadCase</LoadingType>
                    <Id>2</Id>
                    <Items>
                      <ResultOfLoadingItem>
                        <Coefficient>1</Coefficient>
                      </ResultOfLoadingItem>
                    </Items>
                  </Loading>
                  <N>20200.224609375</N>
                  <Qy>0</Qy>
                  <Qz>97851.2109375</Qz>
                  <Mx>0</Mx>
                  <My>-60488.7421875</My>
                  <Mz>0</Mz>
                </SectionResultBase>
              </Results>
            </ResultBase>
          <Results>
        </ResultOnMember>
      <Members>
    <ResultOnMembers>
  <ResultOnMembers>
</OpenModelResult>
```

I currently have something like this but obviously, all the nodes are going to be a child of the OpenModelResult parent. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

```cs
public class OpenModelResult
{
    public string ResultonMembers { get; set; }
    public string Members { get; set; }
    public string ResultonMember { get; set; }
    public string Member { get; set; }
    public string MemberType { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Results { get; set; }
    public string ResultBase { get; set; }
    public string AbsoluteRelative { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string SectionResultBase { get; set; }
    public string Loading { get; set; }
    public string LoadingType { get; set; }
    public string Items { get; set; }
    public string ResultOfLoadingItem { get; set; }
    public string Coefficient { get; set; }
    public double N { get; set; }
    public double Qy { get; set; }
    public double Qz { get; set; }
    public double Mx { get; set; }
    public double My { get; set; }
    public double Mz { get; set; }

    public void Save(string fileName)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlSerializer XML = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OpenModelResult));
            XML.Serialize(stream, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your current class will generate an xml file with 1 parent and the rest childs. if you want to get the example structure you need to define multiple classes. Each child that also is an parent need to be a separate class.

Comment: @Sinatr _"Being in hurry is never a good thing. Please fix `your xml before asking questions`"_ - for all we know this _self-professed, "new to programming"_ and _new contributor to SO_ obtained the XML file from **someone else**.  Which might just well be the case considering OP wants _"`how to serialize an object` so that the XML file has the format shown below"_.  Be nice to new contributors

Comment: @MickyD, I don't see contributor yet. I see broken xml and OP didn't mentioned anything  in regards, meaning he likely did a mistake when pasting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start of the code using Xml Linq.  You already have results i a single class and I think xml linq would be better than xml serialization

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenModelResult result = new OpenModelResult();
            OpenModelResult.results.Add(new OpenModelResult());  // added to test code
            result.Save(FILENAME);
        }

    }
    public class OpenModelResult
    {
        public static List<OpenModelResult> results = new List<OpenModelResult>();
        public string ResultonMembers { get; set; }
        public string Members { get; set; }
        public string ResultonMember { get; set; }
        public string Member { get; set; }
        public string MemberType { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Results { get; set; }
        public string ResultBase { get; set; }
        public string AbsoluteRelative { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string SectionResultBase { get; set; }
        public string Loading { get; set; }
        public string LoadingType { get; set; }
        public string Items { get; set; }
        public string ResultOfLoadingItem { get; set; }
        public string Coefficient { get; set; }
        public double N { get; set; }
        public double Qy { get; set; }
        public double Qz { get; set; }
        public double Mx { get; set; }
        public double My { get; set; }
        public double Mz { get; set; }

        public void Save(string fileName)
        {
            string ident = 
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>" + 
                "<OpenModelResult" + 
                   " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" + 
                   " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                "</OpenModelResult>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement xOpenModelResult = doc.Root;
            XNamespace nsXsi = xOpenModelResult.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xsi");

            XElement xResultOnMembers = new XElement("ResultOnMembers");
            xOpenModelResult.Add(xResultOnMembers);

            XElement xMembers = new XElement("Members");
            xResultOnMembers.Add(xMembers);

            foreach (OpenModelResult result in results)
            {
                XElement xResultOnMember = new XElement("ResultOnMember");
                xMembers.Add(xResultOnMember);

                XElement xMember = new XElement("Member", new object[] {
                    new XElement("MemberType",result.MemberType),
                    new XElement("Id",result.Id),
                });
                xResultOnMember.Add(xMember);

                xResultOnMember.Add(new XElement("ResultType", "InternalForces"));

                XElement xResults = new XElement("Results");
                xResultOnMember.Add(xResults);

                XElement xResultBase = new XElement("ResultBase", new XAttribute(nsXsi + "type", "ResultOnSection"));
                xResults.Add(xResultBase);
 


            }
            doc.Save(fileName);


        }
    }
 
}
```